# Websocket connection failed with nginx and faye

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, faye, private-pub

I'm trying to introduce chatting to my Rails app. For this purpose I used gem private_pub and it works perfectly in development mode.

In production I was using Apache + Passenger, but I couldn't configure Faye with it, so I changed Apache to Nginx. My main app is still on Apache server, and this demo on Nginx with port 8080 (just for test).

I'm able to connect to faye.js by entering *http://chat.mysite.com:8080/faye.js*, but the connection from app throws an error (browser console).

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9292/faye' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

After this error, another error appears every 5 seconds.

> faye.js:2 GET http://localhost:9292/faye?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmeta%2Fhands…22%2C%22callback-polling%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D&jsonp=**jsonp2** net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

*My private_pub.yml*

```
production:
  server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
  secret_token: "mysecret"
  signature_expiration: 3600 # one hour
```

*My private_pub.ru*

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "yaml"
require "faye"
require "private_pub"

Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
PrivatePub.load_config(File.expand_path("../config/private_pub.yml", __FILE__), ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development")
run PrivatePub.faye_app
```

*My nginx site.conf*

```
  server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name www.chat.mysite.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;

  root /var/www/mysite/public;

  location ^~ /faye {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_connect_timeout      90;
     proxy_send_timeout         90;
     proxy_read_timeout         90;
     #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
     proxy_no_cache     $http_pragma $http_authorization;
     break;
    }  
 }
```

If I change private_pub.yml to `http://localhost:9292/faye/faye`, I saw error like "can't load resource /faye/faye.js".

How should I change my Nginx conf or app yml to resolve websocket error?

Comment: in private_pub.yml try changing server into "http://localhost:8080/faye"

Comment: @niceman get an error
application-63199a9….js:14 GET http://localhost:8080/faye.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: hmmm maybe you should put the server name instead of localhost in private_pub.yml, putting localhost will make the client call itself instead of your server I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to configure my private_pub.yml as @niceman said. Now all is working good.

```
production:
  server: "http://my-ip:8080/faye"
```

Answer (score 2):

I see `private_pub` is quite similar to ActionCable in its design. Before you go too far down the road, you may want read my blog post on "[ActionAcable - The good and bad parts](https://blog.ably.io/rails-5-actioncable-the-good-and-bad-parts-1b56c3b31404#.yf1wou9m8)" as it addresses suitable use cases when a system like `private_pub` is good, and when it's not.

If of course you are aware of the shortcomings already, then good luck!