# Connection refused error faye port 9292 private_pub gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tcp, faye, connection-refused, private-pub

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application that uses the gem Private Pub (https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) to have a real time chat messages feature

This application is hosted in Digital Ocean and chat messages have been working correctly for a long time. However, around 1 and a half month ago it stopped working and I got an error on the console that says: GET https://fake-url.com:9292/faye/faye.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

First thing I did was to restart the Faye server using this command: bundle exec thin -C /data/app/shared/config/private_pub_thin.yml -d -P /data/app/shared/tmp/pids/faye.pid --ssl-disable-verify start (I run this command through Capistrano)

After running that command I checked /data/app/shared/tmp/pids folder and confirmed that faye.pid is there so process seems to be running

Then I ran sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN  to check open ports and 9292 port is listed

After that I reloaded the chat and got again the net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Then I checked the ports again and port 9292 does not appear on the list

So it seems like everytime I load the pages it closes the port or something like that.

NOTES:

- ufw is not enabled
- We have a staging server where we have the same problem. Only
  difference is that in staging port 9292 always appears on the list of
  open ports. However, it throws net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
- I think this error started to happen after the old Let’s Encrypt Root
  Certificate expired
  (https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021)
  I am not 100% sure about this but I had other problems related to
  this and I wonder if this error is somehow related to that
- It works fine locally

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is hard to tell from here - it seems related to how things are configured/deployed in Digital Ocean. Can you use curl to test connection/requests to https://fake-url.com:9292/faye/faye.js ?
You can try curl (using full domain remotely) and then maybe the same curl request but locally ie executing it on the machine where your faye is hosted.

Comment: Some users cannot connect to 9292 port. I remember having the same problem in 2013 :). You are 8 years too late. You need to configure nginx to route requests coming from https://yoursite.com/faye to 127.0.0.1:9292/faye, like this user has it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855326/websocket-connection-failed-with-nginx-and-faye?rq=1

Comment: [draganstankovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177154/draganstankovic) Thanks a lot for your answer! I tested the connection with curl from both the remote server and my local server and I got the same error: Connection refused. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: [razvans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3359577/razvans) Thanks for your answer! I changed the port to 8080 in my private_pub.yml file as the guy from the link you shared did and I am still getting an error. Only difference with port 8080 is that it throws a time out error in the javascript console. However, If I test it with curl from the remote server it throws the same connection refused error. The thing is that I haven't changed anything on the server. It stopped working out of the blue which is very weird. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: [draganstankovic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177154/draganstankovic) I ran more tests and noticed that it is only accepting connection from localhost: TCP 127.0.0.1:9292 (LISTEN). If I run `telnet localhost 9292` from the remote server it works but If run `telnet remote_ip 9292` from my computer I get the connection refused error. I am having this exact same problem: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/cannot-connect-to-a-port-over-the-internet-works-from-localhost. Do you know how to make it listen to outside connections?

Comment: I ended up removing Private Pub gem and using Pusher to get the real time updates. Pusher was really easy to use. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing Private Pub gem and using Pusher to get the real time updates. Pusher was really easy to use. Thank you all!